# Android configuration from Jenkins environment variable

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jenkins-plugins

I am using `Jenkins` for CI for my `Android Project`.
There I am having two build, `QA and Dev`. 
For both some of the configurations are different like url and all which i have in my adroid project.

Now my task is to provide some variable in jenkins, and according to that variable only that apk should be built with required config only. Like if i apply for QA build, so only apk with QA config should be generated.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you have 2 flavors in your gradle file, QA and DEV.
If that is the case you can do that from the configuration of your Job.
In Jenkins go to your Job and then to Configurations
Go to the "Build" section and then to task.
That is a textField where you can define which flavor to compile, for example if you want QA you can define the task:

```
assembleQARelease
```

and for DEV

```
assembleDEVRelease
```

In the same way you can define if instead of Release version you want the Debug version or if you create any other flavor for your app just Change QA or DEV for this new one.
Also you can add another task before as Clean or even you can define the 3 of them

```
clean
assembleQARelease
assembleDEVRelease
```

It will clean the project then create the QA release version and then DEV release.